Knot group of mirror image
Are the knot group and the knot group of its mirror image isomorphic?
And,How about the case of knotted surfaces?

Suppose that $K$ is a knot in the three-sphere.  Suppose that $\bar{K}$ is the mirror image of $K$.  Then the fundamental groups of $S^3 - K$ and $S^3 - \bar{K}$ are isomorphic.  Further more, the isomorphism is induced by the orientation-reversing homeomorphism of $S^3$ which takes $K$ to $\bar{K}$.  To see this, consider how the homeomorphism acts on loops in the complement of $K$.
Your second question needs to be clarified. Knotted surfaces where? Knotted how? (You should probably ask one question per question.)
